# Show dialog when activity changes

Tags: android

I use activity A to start background download using `AsyncTask`, when download finished, `AsyncTask.postExecute` will popup a `AlertDialog`. However, during download, I switch to another Activity B **or any other activities**. The result is that the `AlertDialog` can't show out. `AlertDialog` uses activity context(Here should be A). So, how can I show out the `AlertDialog`?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.install));
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        //onSure();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        //onCancle();
    }
});

builder.create().show();
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I need to switch to any other activities, not just activity B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a long running task that can't complete before `Activity A` completes then I would suggest using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). But it depends on what you need. Doing this will allow it to finish in the background and not hold up the `UI`. There are probably other options but this sounds like the best from what I know of your situation. Other than that, you can wait to start the next activity and start it with a button in the dialog once the `AsyncTask` finishes, if that is an option

Answer (score 0):

One option you can do is have a BaseActivity which all of your activities extend from that has a member variable which holds your foreground activity.  When your AsyncTask finishes, you can use the Activity reference from your BaseActivity to show your AlertDialog.  For example:

*file:  MyBaseActivity.java*

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected static Activity sForegroundActivity;

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // do stuff
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

            // cover the edge case where the AsyncTask finished while we are transitioning 
            // between activities and we have not set the foreground activity instance 
            if(sForegroundActivity == null) {
                return;
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(sForegroundActivity);
            builder.setMessage("Showing Dialog in Foreground Activity");
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // handle ok clicked
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // handle cancel clicked
                        }
                    });

            builder.create().show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sForegroundActivity = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sForegroundActivity = null;
    }
}
```

*file: ActivityA.java*

```
public class ActvityA extends MyBaseActivity {

    private void startAsyncTaskAndGoToActivityB() {

        // start our AsyncTask
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        // go to ActivityB.  When the AsyncTask finishes, the AlertDialog will be shown in ActivityB
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```